# Magento admin panel redirecting to a 404 after login

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I recently installed the newest patch to my Magento site (v1.7.0.2) as well as a custom extension called GeoIP from MageWorx.

After installing the above and clearing my cache/sessions, going to log into the site it presents me with the admin login screen as usual, but after I log in correctly the page 404s. The URL is showing a correct back-end URL, but the actual page is a complete 404. No admin panel, no errors.

I've checked the error logs to no avail, I've cleared the cache and sessions multiple times, I've uninstalled the extension by tracing the files it put up and deleted them, I reverted the patch installation, cleared the cache and sessions again, and I'm still not able to get into this site.

It's a multi-store for what it's worth, and any information or help getting pointed in a correct direction would be very much appreciated.

Comment: 404 page or BLANK page? If it shows you a blank page it could be a php error. I would edit index.php and uncomment ini_set('display_errors', 1);. Also make sure compiler is disabled

Comment: It's a 404 page. I've tried the display_errors, and it's not showing any additional info or errors. Also, all of the admin panel pages are redirecting back to the same page, and 404'ing. That page is /admin/sales_order/index/key/.... even if I manually replace sales_order with dashboard, or any other section, it redirects back to sales_order and 404s.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue (Magento CE 1.9.2) - and for me the solution was a question of a setting for the Admin Startup Page ( in System - Configuration - Advanced - Admin - Startup Page )

The list of pages to select are in the current Admin language - but if the default language is different, then you'll (usually) get a 404

... in other words, make sure that you are in the default language when you change this setting, AND change this setting if you change the default language

(for info, the Admin language is set in General - Locale options, with scope of "Default Config". If you want front-end to have different language, then override the same setting with scope of "Main Website")